# Identify a fiction novel about Atlantis and digital or analog "discs"

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to remember a children's fiction book I read as a child.  I only remember vague key words and ideas.  Do you know what this story is?

Language: English

Date read: mid 2000s

Where I would've found it: Midwest USA public library or school library

**Keywords**:

- Atlantis.  Something about an archeological dig finding ruins from Atlantis.
- Analog vs Digital.  The dig found some sort of "disc" in Atlantis that let you control... something.  The villain tried to make a replica of this disc, but something about the replica was digital instead of analog, and so his plan didn't work?
- Elements.  The four Greek elements were in play somehow, and I think there was a scene where characters were talking near a candle flame.  The villain was listening? through the flame or something.
- Golems.  Some sort of elemental being I think called a golem was in the book.  Maybe summoned by the discs?

I've been searching these keywords every time I recall this story, but I don't find anything similar.  I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me find this novel.

Comment: Have you searched here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis_in_popular_culture#After_1900

Comment: @YellowSky Thanks!  I don't recognize any in that list, despite several of them mentioning the Greek elements.  I'm starting to wonder if I dreamed this up...

Comment: This one mentions things digital: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Storm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [The Chaos Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1599901242) by Justin Richards from 2007 about a kid who discovers his archaeologist dad is missing and tries to stop a villain from using an ancient code. Everything you mentioned (Atlantis, the disc, controlling the Elements, candle flames listening in, the golems etc.) is in there.